# Circular motion and car tire angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics

I'm trying to figure out what angle to turn the front tires of my small robotic car (about a foot in length) so that it moves in a circle (on level ground) of radius r (will be accommodating circles of different radii). In addition to being able to set my car's speed, it is equipped with a sensor which includes a gyroscope, accelerometer, and a magnetometer.

I'm just looking for some kind of equation that relates the car's tire angle, the car's speed, the circle's radius, and maybe the angular velocity readings from the gyroscope.

Comment: If you want to do it properly then the angle for each wheel will be different.  Here is one of many links about the steering geometry of a (model) car.  http://www.rctek.com/technical/handling/ackerman_steering_principle.html  If the front wheels are of fixed geometry then you will have to make a compromise.

Comment: What you are asking here falls clearly under engineering and should be part of textbooks on vehicle dynamics.